# First call to JPanel repaint() method creates unwanted background image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I've programmed a Sokoban clone as a project for my study program. Since upgrading to JDK 7, I have following problem: As soon as I call the repaint() method on my `JPanel` for the first time a "shadow image" appears to the right of my JPanel, like so:
Before: [image]
After: [image]

I have no idea what could be causing this, and so don't quite know which code to add.
Here is the paint() Method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    int x;
    int y;

    // draw column
    for (int k = 0; k < field.getField().length; k++) {
        y = (tileWidth * k); // Get y coordinate

        // draw line
        for (int l = 0; l < field.getField()[0].length; l++) {
            FieldObj now = field.getField()[k][l];

            x = (tileWidth * l); // Get x coordinate

            // Wall
            if (now instanceof Wall)
                g.drawImage(Wall, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            // Box
            else if (now instanceof Box && ((Box) now).getStandingOnGoal())
                g.drawImage(BoxOnG, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Box)
                g.drawImage(Box, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            // Man on Goal
            else if (now instanceof Man
                    && field.getMan().getStandingOnGoal()
                    && field.getMan().getOr() == 0)
                g.drawImage(ManGU, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Man
                    && field.getMan().getStandingOnGoal()
                    && field.getMan().getOr() == 1)
                g.drawImage(ManGL, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Man
                    && field.getMan().getStandingOnGoal()
                    && field.getMan().getOr() == 2)
                g.drawImage(ManGR, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Man
                    && field.getMan().getStandingOnGoal()
                    && field.getMan().getOr() == 3)
                g.drawImage(ManGD, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            // Man
            else if (now instanceof Man && field.getMan().getOr() == 0)
                g.drawImage(ManU, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Man && field.getMan().getOr() == 1)
                g.drawImage(ManL, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Man && field.getMan().getOr() == 2)
                g.drawImage(ManR, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else if (now instanceof Man && field.getMan().getOr() == 3)
                g.drawImage(ManD, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            // Floor
            else if (now instanceof Floor && ((Floor) now).getGoal())
                g.drawImage(Goal, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
            else
                g.drawImage(Floor, x, y, tileWidth, tileWidth, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions? Other code you'd like to see?
I'd be grateful for any help.
A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't override paint()!!!

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method and the first statement should generally be:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

to make sure the background is cleared before you do you painting.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics.